# Seg Fault when Parsing a CSV Line in C

Tags: c, csv, segmentation-fault

I am working on a project in which I need to read CSV lines from a text file into my program. I was given a code skeleton, and asked to fill in functionality. I have a struct containing a variable for each type of value I am going to receive, but my char array is causing segmentation faults.
Here is an excerpt of my code.
None of the exerpt is part of the given code, this is all mine:
My error is a Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped), due to the code within the get timestamp space.
my test file contained only one line, 
5, 10:00:10, 1, 997

```
/*
*  YOUR CODE GOES HERE:
*  (1) Read an input csv line from stdin
*  (2) Parse csv line into appropriate fields
*  (3) Take action based on input type:
*        - Check-in or check-out a patient with a given ID
*        - Add a new health data type for a given patient
*        - Store health data in patient record or print if requested
*  (4) Continue (1)-(3) until EOF
*/

/* A new struct to hold all of the values from the csv file */
typedef struct {
    int iD;
    char *time[MAXTIME + 1];
    int value;
    int type;
}csv_input;

/* Declare an instance of the struct, and assign pointers for its values */
csv_input aLine;
int *idptr;
char timeval[MAXTIME + 1];
int *valueptr;
int *typeptr;

/*Note: because the time char is already a pointer, I did not make another one for it but instead dereferenced the pointer I was given */
idptr = &aLine.iD;
int j; /* iterator variable */
for(j; j < MAXTIME; j++){
    *aLine.time[j] = timeval[j];
}
valueptr = &aLine.value;
typeptr = &aLine.type;

/* Get the Patient ID */
*idptr = getchar();
printf("%c", aLine.iD); /* a test to see if my pointers worked and the correct value was read */

/*Skip the first comma */
int next;
next = getchar();

/* get the timestamp */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < MAXTIME; i++)
{
    while ((next = getchar()) != ',')
     {
    timeval[i] = next;
    //printf("%s", aLine.time[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: `*aLine.time[j] = timeval[j];` The pointer array is uninitialised.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
int j; /* iterator variable */
for(j; j < MAXTIME; j++){
```

You need to set `j` to some value, `j=0` makes sense. Without this you're accessing an array with an uninitialized value and you're going to get UB with that.

Second:

```
/*Note: because the time char is already a pointer,
```

No, `time` is an array of pointers to characters, there is a difference there.

This line:

```
*aLine.time[j] = timeval[j];
```

won't work because, for one thing, of your statement `but instead dereference the pointer I was given` is making an incorrect assumption. Yes, you were given an array of pointers, but they don't point to anything, they are uninitialized and as such you can't deference them until you initialize them to a valid non-NULL value.

I think you were trying to do something like this:

```
aLine.time[j] = &timeval; //set the pointer to the local static array
```

but that's only going to work in the local function scope. It'd be better if you malloc to your array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *time[MAXTIME + 1];
```

this is an array of pointers (pointer to char array) and not an array of chars

The crash come from this line

```
*aLine.time[j] = timeval[j];
```

Because as I said `aLine.time[j]` is a pointer and you have not allocated memory for this pointer before filling its content